# Updating a Laravel pivot table when the pivot has a unique field

Tags: laravel, pivot-table

I have two models, User and Service, with a **ManyToMany** relationship. The pivot table has *two* additional fields, `id_code` and `alias`. There may be many relationships between User and Service, but each one is uniquely identified by the field `id_code`. I need to retrieve a specific record in the pivot table by the `id_code`, and update the `alias` for that record only.

**My models:**

**User:**

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    //All attributes & other functions here...

    public function linked_services(){
        return $this->belongsToMany(Service::class)
                        ->withPivot('alias', 'id_code')
                        ->withTimestamps();
    }
}
```

**Service:**

```
class Service extends Model
{
    //All attributes & other functions here...

    public function linked_users(){
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class)
                       ->withPivot('alias', 'id_code')
                       ->withTimestamps();
    }
}
```

**Service-User migration:**

```
Schema::create('service_user', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id')->nullable();
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('service_id');
        $table->string('alias', 50)->nullable();
        $table->string('id_code', 50);

        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
        $table->foreign('service_id')->references('id')->on('services');

        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

In the update function, I get the specific $id_code from a view, but I don't know how to update the "alias" for that specific "id_code".

**What I already tried and is not working:**

```
public function update(Request $request, String $id_code){

    foreach(Auth::user()->linked_services as $service){
        if($service->pivot->id_code === $id_code){
            $service->pivot->alias = $request->alias;
            $service->pivot->save();
        }
    }    
    return redirect()->route('services_user.index');
}
```

This function updates ALL the existing pivot records for the service_user, I need to update only the specific record for an given "id_code".

Answer (score 0):

I solved it!!! I tell you how:

```
Auth::user()->linked_services()
               ->wherePivot('id_code', $id_code)
               ->update(['alias' => $request->alias]);
```

I learned that `$user->linked_services()` (unlike `$user->linked_services`) returns a relationship object (in this case, `belongsToMany`), which contains all the relationship data (intermediate table, pivots, FKs, parent / related objects, etc), and the desired pivot can be accessed on that object with `->wherePivot()`.